# Is NFS proto=udp supported in RHEL 8 nfs-utils-2.3?

Tags: rhel, nfs, udp

I can get `vers=3` to happen, and I can get `mountproto=udp` to happen, but I cannot get a `proto=udp` to happen on the nfs client.  I can only get `proto=tcp` on the nfs client.

Is `proto=udp` supported in nfs-utils 2.3.3 that is in RHEL 8.8 ?

here is the original conf files, what can be changed to achieve `proto=udp` on the nfs client?

setting `tcp=n` in `nfs.conf` results in a failed `service nfs-server start`, no matter how I seem to alter anything else.

```
# /etc/nfs.conf
# This is a general configuration for the
# NFS daemons and tools
#
[general]
# pipefs-directory=/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
#
[nfsrahead]
# nfs=15000
# nfs4=16000
#
[exportfs]
# debug=0
#
[gssd]
# verbosity=0
# rpc-verbosity=0
# use-memcache=0
# use-machine-creds=1
use-gss-proxy=1
# avoid-dns=1
# limit-to-legacy-enctypes=0
# context-timeout=0
# rpc-timeout=5
# keytab-file=/etc/krb5.keytab
# cred-cache-directory=
# preferred-realm=
# set-home=1
# upcall-timeout=30
# cancel-timed-out-upcalls=0
#
[lockd]
# port=0
# udp-port=0
#
[mountd]
# debug=0
# manage-gids=n
# descriptors=0
# port=0
# threads=1
# reverse-lookup=n
# state-directory-path=/var/lib/nfs
# ha-callout=
# cache-use-ipaddr=n
# ttl=1800
#
[nfsdcld]
# debug=0
# storagedir=/var/lib/nfs/nfsdcld
#
[nfsdcltrack]
# debug=0
# storagedir=/var/lib/nfs/nfsdcltrack
#
[nfsd]
# debug=0
# threads=8
# host=
# port=0
# grace-time=90
# lease-time=90
# tcp=y
# vers2=n
# vers3=y
# vers4=y
# vers4.0=y
# vers4.1=y
# vers4.2=y
# rdma=n
# rdma-port=20049
#
[statd]
# debug=0
# port=0
# outgoing-port=0
# name=
# state-directory-path=/var/lib/nfs/statd
# ha-callout=
# no-notify=0
#
[sm-notify]
# debug=0
# force=0
# retry-time=900
# outgoing-port=
# outgoing-addr=
# lift-grace=y
#
```

---

```
#
# /etc/nfsmount.conf - see nfsmount.conf(5) for details
#
# This is an NFS mount configuration file. This file can be broken
# up into three different sections: Mount, Server and Global
# 
# [ MountPoint "Mount_point" ] 
# This section defines all the mount options that
# should be used on a particular mount point. The '<Mount_Point>'
# string need to be an exact match of the path in the mount 
# command. Example:
#     [ MountPoint "/export/home" ]
#       background=True
# Would cause all mount to /export/home would be done in
# the background
#
# [ Server "Server_Name" ]
# This section defines all the mount options that
# should be used on mounts to a particular NFS server. 
# Example:
#     [ Server "nfsserver.foo.com" ]
#       rsize=32k
#       wsize=32k
# All reads and writes to the 'nfsserver.foo.com' server 
# will be done with 32k (32768 bytes) block sizes.
#
[ NFSMount_Global_Options ]
# This statically named section defines global mount 
# options that can be applied on all NFS mount.
#
# Protocol Version [2,3,4]
# This defines the default protocol version which will
# be used to start the negotiation with the server.
# Defaultvers=4
#
# Setting this option makes it mandatory the server supports the
# given version. The mount will fail if the given version is 
# not support by the server. 
# Nfsvers=4
#
# Network Protocol [udp,tcp,rdma] (Note: values are case sensitive)
# This defines the default network protocol which will
# be used to start the negotiation with the server.
# Defaultproto=tcp
#
# Setting this option makes it mandatory the server supports the
# given network protocol. The mount will fail if the given network
# protocol is not supported by the server.
# Proto=tcp
#
# The number of times a request will be retired before 
# generating a timeout 
# Retrans=2
#
# The number of minutes that will retry mount
# Retry=2
#
# The minimum time (in seconds) file attributes are cached
# acregmin=30
#
# The Maximum time (in seconds) file attributes are cached
# acregmin=60
#
# The minimum time (in seconds) directory attributes are cached
# acregmin=30
#
# The Maximum time (in seconds) directory attributes are cached
# acregmin=60
#
# Enable Access  Control  Lists
# Acl=False
#
# Enable Attribute Caching
# Ac=True
#
# Do mounts in background (i.e. asynchronously)
# Background=False
#
# Close-To-Open cache coherence
# Cto=True
#
# Do mounts in foreground (i.e. synchronously)
# Foreground=True
#
# How to handle times out from servers (Hard is STRONGLY suggested)
# Hard=True
# Soft=False
#
# Enable File Locking
# Lock=True
#
# Enable READDIRPLUS on NFS version 3 mounts
# Rdirplus=True
#
# Maximum Read Size (in Bytes)
# Rsize=8k
#
# Maximum Write Size (in Bytes)
# Wsize=8k
#
# Maximum Server Block Size (in Bytes)
# Bsize=8k
#
# Ignore unknown mount options
# Sloppy=False
#
# Share Data and Attribute Caches
# Sharecache=True
#
# The amount of time, in tenths of a seconds, the client
# will wait for a response from the server before retransmitting
# the request.
# Timeo=600
#
# Sets all attributes times to the same time (in seconds)
# actimeo=30
#
# Server Mountd port mountport
# mountport=4001
#
# Server Mountd Protocol
# mountproto=tcp
#
# Server Mountd Version
# mountvers=3
#
# Server Mountd Host
# mounthost=hostname
#
# Server Port
# Port=2049
#
# RPCGSS security flavors 
# [none, sys, krb5, krb5i, krb5p ]
# Sec=sys
#
# Allow Signals to interrupt file operations
# Intr=True
#
# Specifies  how the kernel manages its cache of directory
# Lookupcache=all|none|pos|positive
#
# Turn of the caching of that access time
# noatime=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the *server* doesn't support UDP.  You need to update `/etc/nfs.conf` so there's a `udp=y` line in the `[nfsd]` section.

```
# nfsconf --dump
[gssd]
 use-gss-proxy = 1

[nfsd]
 udp = y
```

Now a simple test export:

```
/tmp/test  -rw,no_root_squash,insecure *
```

And we can mount this:

```
# mount -o nfsvers=3,proto=udp localhost:/tmp/test /mnt
```

We can verify this is using UDP:

```
# mount | grep mnt
localhost:/tmp/test on /mnt type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=udp,timeo=11,retrans=3,sec=sys,mountaddr=127.0.0.1,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=127.0.0.1)
```

Yup, we can see "udp" in there.

This was tested on Rocky 8.8

```
# rpm -q nfs-utils
nfs-utils-2.3.3-59.el8.x86_64
```